# NullPointerException - on setContentView with SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, supportmapfragment

I have a crash report with a **NPE** after **setContentView** with an **SupportMapFragment** on a **Android 5** device!

**View:**

```
            <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

**Code statement on crash:**

```
setContentView(R.layout.misc);
```

**The Exception:**
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

The class seems is on the phone otherwise I should get a **ClassNotFound** Exception.

So what causes the **NPE**?

Comment: have you followed Google tutorial? with the all the permissions and keys?

Comment: Can you reproduce locally?  Or is this just seen in crash reports?  Either way, add your relevant code to the question...

Comment: @Daniel: I can't reproduce. It is working fine here. I have only 1 crash report from 1 user at the moment. It crashes on setContentView(), so what relevant code do you mean?

Comment: @Itzik: It is working fine here on all my devices. And 99 % of users too. Only one user crash at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Which IDE you use Eclipse or Android Studio. Problem in your library which you have used for Google Map integration.

Comment: As I mentioned it works in the emualtor and it works on all my devices. So no problem at all. Only on some phones it crashes with the NPE.

Comment: I use newest version in gradle: compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0" and my activity extends AppCompatActivity!

Comment: When using the native action bar, ABS simply proxies setContentView to the framework or just stop calling setContentView multiple times.

First: You are calling findViewById() when the activity is instantiated and its member variables are initialized. The activity won't have a Window yet and it will NPE. Call findViewById() only in onCreate() or later, after setContentView().

Second : You do not have setContentView() with a view hierarchy that has a view with the given id. null is returned and invoking method on it will NPE.

Comment: Thanks, but it is working on all my phones and on the emualtor and on 95 % of the users! So it crashes only on 2 or 5 users phones and I want to prevent this.

So if I call it twice or something similar it would crash everywhere.
So I think there is missing something on this phones.